# How to read a file in parts of datatables?

Tags: python, datatable

I have a compressed file of 5 GB, and the decompressed file is over 80 GB. I would like to read it in parts using the datatables library for python. In pandas it looks like this

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file,compression='gzip',encoding='utf-8',chunksize=10**5): 
chunk.head(10)
```

How to do it in datatables ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `memory_limit` option in the [official API for `datatable.fread(...)`](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dt/fread.html#datatable-fread).

The docs suggest that simply be using this parameter, the amount of RAM will be considered, resulting in a combined on-disk and in-memory storage access. While this works to solve the RAM issue, it does not appear to do quite that same thing as your `pandas` example.

The workflow they suggest is *after* creating the `Frame` from `datatable.fread(...)`, filter down to a smaller subset of this data (like an `ndarray` view in `numpy`), then call the [`materialize(...)`](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame/materialize.html#datatable-frame-materialize) method to assert the current subset is in RAM. This part is closer to your `pandas` example, it just required the full loading by `datatable.fread(...)` first.